# Change inner tuples in Json files with Python

Tags: python, json

I have a Json that looks like:

```
[
  {
    "id": "a199ffc8-86d3-4ed1-a5e1-87ed11b89e21",
    "times": [
      {
        "start": 1543683600000,
        "end": 1543791600000
      },
      {
        "start": 1543827600000,
        "end": 1543899600000
      }
    ],
    "priority": "P1"
  },
  {
    "id": "e9d5ad69-806b-4c77-8be4-5be6d41db1c9",
    "times": [
      {
        "start": 1543647600000,
        "end": 1543683600000
      },
      {
        "start": 1543719600000,
        "end": 1543755600000
      }
    ],
    "priority": "P1"
  }]
```

I am trying to change "start" and "end" time stamps but I can't figure out completly how to do it. U wrote something like:

```
from datetime import timedelta


with open('events.json') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file, )


day_start = 28
for tuple in data:
    tuple['start'] =  (calendar.timegm(time.gmtime()) - int(timedelta(days = day_start).total_seconds()))*1000
    tuple['end'] =  (calendar.timegm(time.gmtime()) - int(timedelta(days = day_start-1).total_seconds()))*1000
    day_start -= 2


with open('dataEvents.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(data, outfile)
```

Any suugestion what to change in order to get into the right fields?

Comment: What is your expected output? How do you want to see the "start" and "end" times?Also, you are dealing with a list dictionaries and not tuples.

Comment: Looks like you are trying to solve the problem all at once - break the problem down: if you print `data` you will see that it is a list so you need to iterate on the list - then print each entry in the list, you will see it is a dictionary so you can work out which field to access, an so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to turn back time by some amount of days for every `start` and `end` of your data you need to iterate over `times` key of your dict's elements not just over all the elements of your dict.

```
import time

print('before:')
print(*data[0]['times'], sep='\n')
print(*data[1]['times'], sep='\n')

day_start = 28
for i in data:
    for pair in i['times']:
        pair['start'] = int((time.time() - day_start*60*60*24) * 1000)
        pair['end'] = int((time.time() - day_start-1*60*60*24) * 1000)
        day_start -= 2

print('\nafter:')
print(*data[0]['times'], sep='\n')
print(*data[1]['times'], sep='\n')
```

**Output**

```
before:
{'end': 1543791600000, 'start': 1543683600000}
{'end': 1543899600000, 'start': 1543827600000}
{'end': 1543683600000, 'start': 1543647600000}
{'end': 1543755600000, 'start': 1543719600000}

after:
{'end': 1547892092406, 'start': 1545559320406}
{'end': 1547892094406, 'start': 1545732120406}
{'end': 1547892096406, 'start': 1545904920406}
{'end': 1547892098406, 'start': 1546077720406}
```